# why do checkbox events give panic: ValueOf: invalid value

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

I have a very normal golang wasm setup. A wasm_exec.js from go 1.21.0 and everything is working great. I can call:

```
button.Set("onclick", js.FuncOf(MyClick))
```

and lots of other stuff. But then I tried:

```
box.Set("onchange", js.FuncOf(CheckChange))
```

and everytime I get:

`panic: ValueOf: invalid value`

```
syscall/js.ValueOf({0x3d540, 0xeffe8}) wasm_exec.js:22:14
    /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js/js.go:209 +0xf6 wasm_exec.js:22:14
syscall/js.Value.Set({{}, 0x7ff800010000014a, 0x180d8b0}, {0xa3cfd, 0x6}, {0x3d540, 0xeffe8}) wasm_exec.js:22:14
    /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js/js.go:306 +0x8 wasm_exec.js:22:14
syscall/js.handleEvent() wasm_exec.js:22:14
    /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js/func.go:103 +0x26
```

If you look at the go source:

```
  cb := jsGo.Get("_pendingEvent")
  cb.Set("result", result)
```

the `cb.Set` line is throwing the panic. Why only for onchange checkbox events?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
return js.ValueOf(true) vs return js.Undefined()
```

the button click func can return Undefined but a checkbox needs a bool return value!